# Backup programs and program data?

Tags: backup, format, data-recovery

Hi AskUbuntu community,

I'm going to format my hard drive and install a new version of Ubuntu.
I want to backup some programs, not only sync data, I want to have ready-to-restore apps and their data, also offline.

Any tool that can help?